# Monthly allowance spent

Tags: fractions, word-problem

Devi spent **(2/3)** of her monthly allowance on food and **(5/6)** of the remaining amount on stationery. She spent $35 more on food than on stationery. How much as Devi's monthly allowance?

My work:

Number of allowance = A
Number spent on Food = F
Number spent on Stationary = S

[1] We know Devi spent (2/3) of her allowance. 
so **1 - (2/3) = 1/3A** (so 1/3 of her allowance is left)

[2] We know she spent (5/6) of her remaining allowance. So **(1/3) * (5/6) = 5/18A** (I'm guessing 5/18A is the amount of allowance left?)

[3] She spent $35 more on food than on stationery. So, (F + 35) + S = A

[4] We plug it into this forum (F + 35) + S = A
**(1/3A + 35) + 5/18A = A**

Answer: A = 90

If this is correct, is there a better way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the correct answer, but you could clean up your reasoning as follows:

Define A to be total allowance, F to be allowance spent on food, and S to be allowance spent on stationary.

Since she spent 35 more on stationary than on food, then $35+S=F$. Also, $F=(2/3)A$ and $S=(5/6)(A-F)=(5/6)(A-(2/3)A)=(5/6)(1/3)A=(5/18)A$

Using substitution, $35+(5/18)A=(2/3)A$ so $A=90$.

Comment: And in $[2]$, you say that $(5/18)A$ is the amount of allowance left, but this value is really the amount of allowance she spends on stationary.